# You database files were created by PostgreSQL 9.0- could not find executables for this version

Tags: linux, postgresql, opensuse

I attempted to update the version of Postgres-server on an OpenSuse server. There were a few issues and I now want to revert back to using the version of postgres-server that was installed before(9.03).
I've removed version 9.4 and I've tried starting the postgresql server but I'm getting the error:

```
Your database files were created by PostgreSQL version 9.0.
 Could not find executables for this version.
 Please install the PostgreSQL server package for version 9.0.
```

When I run:

```
rpm -qa | grep postgresql
```

it shows:

```
postgresql-docs-9.0.3-1.6.1.noarch
postgresql-server-9.0.3-1.6.1.x86_64
postgresql-contrib-9.0.3-1.6.1.x86_64
postgresql-9.0.3-1.6.1.x86_64
postgresql-devel-9.0.3-1.6.1.x86_64
```

So it looks like version 9.03 is already installed.

I'm not sure what to do now to get the server back to how it was and I'm panicking a bit. Can anyone suggest anything?

EDIT**

Here some more info after some useful info from Ronaldhino.

I discovered my pg_ctl file in /user/bin/pg_ctl and /data appears to be the previous data directory (I deduced this as it contain pg_hbs.conf and postgresql.conf). 
As a result I've run this command as user postgres:

```
/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D /data/ -l /data/pg_log/new_log.txt
```

I did get a message initial saying:

```
server starting
```

It appears that the server is actually running. However, the psql binary file now appears to be missing so I can't psql into the database service.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems that system can not recognize where's your postgresql 9.0 location is.

You should find where's the postgresql 9.0's binary file and start Server directly.

1. Run command for finding where's postgresql 9.0 location

   `which postgres`

   For example:
   /usr/local/pgsql/bin/
2. Start server

   `sudo /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -D <<your DB dir>> -l /var/log/postgresl.log`

Good luck!

Comment: Firstly thanks for the advice. It has gotten me over one hurdle (I think!) now I've found another!. I've edited my question. Cheers

Comment: For your editted question: try tailf /data/pg_log/new_log.txt for know what error is